# Unable to find template "BloggerBlogBundle:Page:index.html.twig"

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.1

I'm practicing Symfony 3.1 And i start a tutorial [How to create blog part 1](http://tutorial.symblog.co.uk/docs/configuration-and-templating.html).
It's my second project.

So i've got an error Unable to find template "BloggerBlogBundle:Page:index.html.twig" (looked into: \htdocs\Blogger\app/Resources/views, \htdocs\Blogger\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bridge\Twig/Resources/views/Form).
I think the problem is that i'm using symfony 3.1...
P.S. And i stoped on "We are now ready to view our blogger template"
Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 2):

That's a Symfony2 tutorial. Symfony3 uses the src folder for twig templates.

For example `src/Resources/views/default/index.html.twig`.

Try placing your twig template in:

src/Blogger/BlogBundle/Resources/views/Default/index.html.twig

Create the folder path `Blogger/BlogBundle/Resources/views/Default` if it doesn't exist.

I highly suggest going through the [Symfony3 Book](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/index.html) instead.

Comment: It didn't help, thanks anyway. I will read this book. Can you recommend few link with examples(i think i need more practice)?

Comment: I would actually suggest going through that Book from beginning to end. For example starting from "Symfony and HTTP Fundamentals". I know it would take a while, but I've been going through the Book (even for reference) now for about 4 months. Symfony2 is very different than Symfony3. Doctrine has their [own documentation here](http://www.doctrine-project.org/), and I'm sure you'll like Doctrine once you get familiar with it.